# Multiple checkboxes with Different label in Loop

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $r=mysql_query("SELECT city.id as city_id, locality.id,locality.area_name  ".
                   "FROM city, locality  ".
                   "WHERE city.id = locality .city_id order by city_id"); 

    while($rss=mysql_fetch_object($r))
    {
?>
<legend><?=$rss->city_id?></legend>
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_type[]" id="sub_type" value="<?=$rss->id?>" />
<span><?=$rss->area_name?></span><br/>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I am displaying area names with their city ID as a label. The problem is that this ID label is added for each area name due to the surrounding while loop. How can I prevent the ID label from being repeated multiple times, so that the checkboxes are grouped under the city ID they belong to?

Comment: http://www.99acres.com/property/advanced_search.php     check locations i want display like this my record

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<legend>` so it is *outside* the while loop.

(And use a `<label>` not a `<span>` … you'll need to fix the `id` of your inputs too, they have to be *unique*)

Comment: if this take out from loop it shows only one result but i have 9 cities id

Comment: @user1138383 Legend isn't used for labelling inputs, it's used for labelling fieldsets.

Comment: 99acres.com/property/advanced_search.php  it is working example see locations in this

Comment: i have issue in while loop how to control that city-id not repeat

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<?php
$r=mysql_query("SELECT city.id as city_id, locality.id,locality.area_name  ".
               "FROM city, locality  ".
               "WHERE city.id = locality .city_id order by city_id"); 
$previous = '';
while($rss=mysql_fetch_object($r)) { ?>
    <?php if (empty($previous) || $previous != $rss->city_id) { ?>
        <legend><?=$rss->city_id?></legend>
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php $previous = $rss->city_id; ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_type[]" id="sub_type" value="<?=$rss->id?>" />
    <span><?=$rss->area_name?></span><br/>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: wao working perfect thanx...i appreciate your answer...quick and accurate

Comment: @user1138383 if the answer helped you, and you want to show others that it did, please click the arrow (turn it green) so that everyone else knows he helped you. This is how our community works (and gives you "more reputation" as well). It's all based on gamification, and you're giving him a checkmark will help him "level up" soon. :D

Comment: aw schucks, nothing doing. It's all about the gamification

Comment: i have a problem in this community.my original account is disable to post questions. how can i fix this issue ? can you help?

Comment: @user1138383: Soory, I don't know. May be ask moderators how to do it.

Comment: @$M42: I want do same thing in Select Box like that first show city id and then show area name in select box how could i do this ?

Comment: @user1138383: Please ask a new question with an example of desired output.

Comment: http://www.99acres.com/ check here city list box red colors are city and and below whites are there childs ..its same like check box as you solved .now this is in select box.plz see example and reply

Comment: @user1138383: I'll be glad to help you if you post another question. It's not usual to ask 2 questions in the same post.